# Add search box to Newsletter style list

Tags: list, search

I have created a very basic FAQ using a custom list. We want to use the ‘newsletter’ style but when doing this the search box disappears. It only seems to appear in default view. The setting is turned on.

Does anyone know how we can use the default list search box in newsletter view?

Answer (score 3):

The default Search box is only available in default view style.

1. As a workaround you can set default view style and change it's look and feel using CSR.
2. Another workaround is add text filter webpart on page and connect it to your list webpart (But in this, we can apply filter on only one column in list & we also need to enter exact value which we want to search.)